# TCL 8.4 workaround for not having the lsort -nocase option?

Tags: sorting, tcl, case-insensitive

I'm doing a simple TCL **lsort** using the **-nocase** flag. However, one system where I'm running that code is still using **TCL 8.4**, where the nocase isn't available. Is there any simple workaround, or will I have to manually handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCL 8.4 has the -dictionary flag, which provides case-insensitive comparisons. If your strings contain no digits on it, I think the behaviour is equal to the -nocase flag.

From the documentation:

**-dictionary**
    Use dictionary-style comparison. This is the same as -ascii except (a) case is ignored except as a tie-breaker and (b) if two strings contain embedded numbers, the numbers compare as integers, not characters. For example, in -dictionary mode, bigBoy sorts between bigbang and bigboy, and x10y sorts between x9y and x11y.

**-nocase**
    Causes comparisons to be handled in a case-insensitive manner. Has no effect if combined with the -dictionary, -integer, or -real options.

http://www.hume.com/html85/mann/lsort.html

Comment: Thanks for that! I can probably live with the fact that numbers are treated as integers, but it's not ideal. But I'll wait to see if anyone else gives an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Schwartzian transform:

```
set lst {This is a Mixed Case sentence and this is the End}
set tmp [list]
foreach word $lst {lappend tmp [list $word [string tolower $word]]}
unset lst
foreach pair [lsort -index 1 $tmp] {lappend lst [lindex $pair 0]}
puts $lst
```

outputs

```
a and Case End is is Mixed sentence the This this
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own string comparison procedure:

```
proc nocaseCompare {a b} {
    set a [string tolower $a]
    set b [string tolower $b]
    if {$a < $b} {
        return -1
    } elseif {$a > $b} {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}


set lst {This is a Mixed Case sentence and this is the End}
puts [lsort -command nocaseCompare $lst]
```

Output:

```
a and Case End is is Mixed sentence the This this
```